# how to deal with multiple countdown timer in a listview builder

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, timer, countdown

I'm using listView builder for view and every data for this list comes from http response.
I'm setting all the data in builder return widget but I don't know how to manage timer for each children of listview.builder.
Start and end time i getting from response.

Im also posting a image for more clarity that what exactly i need.

[image: This image view i need]

Comment: could you please add code here for better answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Inside listview builder you can add countdown timer:

```
CountdownTimer(
  textStyle: TextStyle(
      fontSize: 14, color: Colors.red, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
  onEnd: onEnd,
  endTime: countRemainsTime(item.startDateTime, item.endDateTime),
  endWidget: Text(
    "Deal has ended",
    style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 14,
        color: appColorDeepGreen,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
  ),
);
```

and count remaining time using following method:

```
  var current = DateTime.now();

countRemainsTime(String startTime, String endTime) {
var end = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(int.parse(endTime));

var countdowndiff = end.difference(current).inSeconds;

var finalTimer = current.millisecondsSinceEpoch +
    Duration(seconds: countdowndiff).inMilliseconds;

controller = CountdownTimerController(
    endTime: finalTimer, onEnd: onEnd, vsync: this);

return finalTimer;
```

}

Comment: didn't find CountdownTimer

Comment: please share your code

Answer (score 0):

Add this library to pubspec.yaml file :
`flutter_countdown_timer: ^4.1.0`
and use above code